# rsync command not found

Tags: rsync, macos

I am a total novice that is attempting to use rsync to back up my photos stored on my Macbook Pro.  After following the instructions from some excellent Youtube videos, I finally had it up and operating (for a while). Then, on subsequent backup attempts, it suddenly stopped.I have attempted repairs after doing much research and video time, but without success. The command I use and the result is detailed below.

```
rsync -av /Volumes/ON1_PHOTOS/ /Volumes/Experimental/
-bash: rsync: command not found
```

Hoping for some assistance.

Comment: So, you used to be able to use `rsync` on your macOS system and now you can't no longer do so. This means that you've either changed your `$PATH` variable in your shell's startup files, or possibly uninstalled `rsync`. How did you install `rsync` and what is the value of `$PATH` in your shell (`echo "$PATH"`). Also, if you open a new terminal window, does it still not work?

Comment: You didn't say which instructions from which videos you followed, but one way to install an up-to-date version of rsync is via Homebrew, and if you accidentally uninstalled it, it's easy to install it again.

Comment: Opening a new Terminal window did not help.  If I inadvertently uninstalled rsync, I am so new at this that I would not know how to reinstall it.  The rsync I have/had was included with my Macbook.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/rsync` and `echo "$PATH"` in your question so we can get a better idea of what your environment looks like.